# How to Integrate react-native-swiper using flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-swiper

I was trying to integrate react-native-swiper, which loads videos in it.
I am looking for a way to integrate it with a flat list. but the data is not loading properly, is there any alternative way to load data using flat list (using array.map())

```
export default class HomeTab extends Component {
    render() {
     return (
       <FlatList
          data={Data}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
          renderItem={({item}) =>

            <Swiper style={styles.wrapper} 
                showsButtons={false}
                horizontal={true}
                loop={false}
                index={item.id}
                activeDot={
                  <View></View>
                }
                dot={
                  <View></View>
                }
                >
                  <View style={styles.slide1}>
                            <Video 
                                source={{uri: item.media}}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
                                ref={(ref) => {
                                  this.player = ref
                                }}        
                                resizeMode={'contain'}
                                style={styles.backgroundVideo} 
                        />

                      </View>
            </Swiper>

            }
          />
    )
  }
}
```

using npm package: react-native-swiper https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swiper

Comment: What error are you getting? You seem to be creating a swiper for every `item` instead of the swiper being the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this lib, cause [react-native-swiper-flatlist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swiper-flatlist) it has flatlist inside
Example below:

```
  <SwiperFlatList
        autoplay
        autoplayDelay={3}
        index={3}
        autoplayLoop
        data={items}
        renderItem={({item}) => // Standard Image
                            <View style={[styles.child, { backgroundColor: '#000' }]}>
                                <Image
                                    source={{uri:item.key}}
                                    style={styles.checkoutSliderImage}
                                />
                                <Text>{item.key}</Text>
                            </View>
                        }
        showPagination
      />
```